# How can I show my hidden administrator account through a guest account?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator

I have hidden my administrator account on windows logon screen through regedit/.../specialaccounts/userlist/... but now i cannot make it show up again, because I can't change the value from 0 to 1 on a guest account and I only have access to the guest account on this pc.

Can anyone tell me how to make my admin account show up again? (without using regedit)

Comment: Did you try [starting Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7)?

Comment: Didn't work, it still wasn't there. Or can I edit the value through guest account in safe mode? Because it is forbidden for me to change the regedit value as a normal guest account....

Comment: There's another admin account but I don't know the password for it, for it is the computer of my sister.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the *password* of the Administrator account, you can run regedit as an administrator, either by doing a search for "regedit" in the start menu and then right-click and do "Run As Administrator"; or by starting a command shell as administrator and run `regedit` in there, or by using [runas](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html).

All methods require knowledge of the Administrator password.

If you get really stuck, you can boot a Linux live CD that lets you install packages -- e.g. Ubuntu -- and use `chntpw` to set the Administrator password, then you can perform the method as above. See [here](http://lifehacker.com/5584762/edit-the-windows-registry-from-a-linux-thumb-drive) for an okay article (it's not very well-written) with details on that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it would've helped if I had made a password. I guess it only works if you put up a password for the admin account.

Comment: Boot up through a Linux live CD, then. You can bypass the Windows security model this way as long as you do not have Full Disk Encryption enabled.

Comment: I'll try when I have time for it, thx.

Answer (score 0):

- `Win+R` -> `cmd` -> `runas /user:COMPUTER_NAME\ADMIN_ACCOUNT cmd`
- Enter password.
- In the elevated window open: `regedit`
- Edit the key.